# CSS Grid: Invalid Property Value

Tags: css, css-grid

I am trying to create a css grid with 3 columns and N rows.  The first two rows should have a sidebar in the rightmost column, but when I do this, I get an "Invalid property value" message from the inspector.  Any ideas why?  Here is my css:

```css
.thumbnails {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "thumbnail thumbnail sidebar" 
    "thumbnail thumbnail sidebar" 
    "thumbnail thumbnail thumbnail";
}

.thumbnail {
  grid-area: thumbnail;
}

.sidebar {
  grid-area: sidebar;
}
```

```html
<div class="thumbnails">
  <div class="sidebar">
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnail">
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnail">
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnail">
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnail">
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnail">
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnail">
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnail">
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnail">
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnail">
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnail">
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnail">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grid-Areas must be **rectangular** so your prospective layout will not compute as it is "L"-shaped.

```
.thumbnails {
     display: grid;
     grid-template-areas:
        "thumbnail thumbnail sidebar"
        "thumbnail thumbnail sidebar"
        "thumbnail thumbnail thumbnail";

    }
```

From your description:

> The first two rows should have a sidebar in the rightmost column

you would require

```
.thumbnails {
     display: grid;
     grid-template-areas:
        "thumbnail thumbnail sidebar"
        "thumbnail thumbnail sidebar"
        "thumbnail thumbnail .";

    }
```

Comment: Great answer. What does the `.` do?

Comment: " a period signifies an empty grid cell" - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/#prop-grid-template-areas

Comment: Oh, thanks!  How do I specify that the cells below the sidebar should not contain sidebar elements though?  Because I would imagine that the . would also match elements with grid-area: sidebar, no?

Comment: If the . represents an empty grid cell, that won't work, because there need to be thumbnails beneath the sidebar.

Comment: You can't do that...as I said, grid-area must be rectangular. It sounds as though you want something more akin to *floated* sidebar and that's not possible with CSS-Grid.

Comment: Huh, that is disappointing.  I thought the whole point of css grid was to be able to do easily weird layouts like this.  Oh, well.  Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: @Paulie_D Certainly that's possible with CSS grid, it just cannot be done using template areas.

Comment: I didn't say it couldn't be done, I just answered the question.